# How to get unique or distinct user comments?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

User has many Posts and many Comments. Posts has many Comments.

If I have `@post`, how do I get all unique user comments of this post?

For example. User Foo and user Bar have comments on @post. User Foo has 10 comments, while user Bar has 5 comments.

The result only needs to return Foo and Bar. How do I go about this?

I tried the following to no avail:

```
@post.comments.select('DISTINCT users.email').joins(:user)
```

Im using MySql by the way.

Comment: Does `:user` `has_many :comments` ?

Comment: Yep, `:user has_many :comments`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by "needs to return Foo and Bar" you mean the users Foo and Bar.

If an array will do, consider this:

`@post.comments.collect(&:user).uniq`

Comment: What if I need to return a hash object instead of an array?

Comment: What do you expect to be in the hash? This will return an array of User objects.

Comment: No problem. A quick note, though, this will only work when an array will do. In the case of most common forms of pagination, this will not work out of the box. In an event where you do need an association, such as for will_paginate, I suggest creating a scope instead.

Comment: I beleive Kaminari supports array pagination. I remember having to paginate through an array result set (for another project) and Kaminari did well. One of the reasons why I am now using Kaminari